# Shiny deployment - failed upload and gibberish in messages / error

Tags: r, shiny

The company I work for recently did *something* and I can no longer deploy my apps (including ones that work, have been previously deployed, and not changed since last deployment). The messages I get are... gibberish?

[image]

and

[image]

I couldn't find similar issues when googling. Can anyone shed any light? I don't even know where to start on fixing this... I'll be happy to add more info on session or whatever else as required.

Comment: The messages aren't quite gibberish. If you look closely you'll see that basically the odd characters are supposed to be quote symbols. It's unclear what operating systems are involved here but it looks like there is a mismatch in the text encoding used. How exactly are you deploying your apps? Your own shiny server or shinyapps.io?

Comment: Its mojibaked ! Your compiler has an encoding error, it looks like CP1252 instead of UTF-8 . whats the output of    l10n_info()  ?

Comment: if you use Rstudio try File -> Reopen with encoding -> UTF-8

Comment: @MrFlick I'm on Windows, deploying to shinyapps.io. Been doing this for almost a year now, first time I'm seeing this happen... @user1225645 - output of ` l10n_info()` is: `$MBCS = FALSE, $UTF-8 = FALSE,  $Latin-1 = TRUE, $codepage = 1252, $system.codepage  = 1252`. The RStudio hint did the trick. But I don't normally work in RStudio, just straight-up R. Any suggestions on how to get this sorted out in R? Either way, if you want to write an answer, I'll accept it! Huge thanks for the fix!